# ref is not defined react

Tags: reactjs, react-forwardref

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';

const Post = forwardRef(({name, description, message, photoUrl }) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref} className="post">
      <div className="post_header">
        <Avatar src={photoUrl}>{name[0]}</Avatar>
        <div className="post_info">
          <h2>{name}</h2> 
          <p>{description}</p>
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div className="post_body">
        <p>{message}</p> 
      </div>
      <div className="post_buttons">
        <InputOption Icon={ThumbUpAltIcon} title="Like" color="gray" />
        <InputOption Icon={ChatIcon} title="Comment" color="gray" />
        <InputOption Icon={ShareIcon} title="Share" color="gray" />
        <InputOption Icon={SendIcon} title="Send" color="gray" />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
});
```

es-lint error 'ref' is not defined

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the `ref` arg after the `props` arg:

```
const Post = forwardRef(({name, description, message, photoUrl }, ref) => {
```

[Forwarding refs to dom components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components).

Answer (score 0):

you are missing this `ref` while wrapping. See below code:-

```
const Post = forwardRef(({name, description, message, photoUrl }, ref) => { 
return (... )}
```